# How to extract this information

Tags: c++

I have come across questions of this type so many times in C++ that I felt it's about time I learn this technique. I know how it's done in Java, but I'm still a novice in C++.

Suppose I have a text file which contains some dates in this format:

```
May 3rd, 2014, /
December 4th, 2011, -
January 19th, 200, -
January 1st, 2011, /
March 3rd, 1900, /
```

The last char in each line is like a date separator as shown below.

How can I convert them to this format and write in another text file:

```
5/3/2014
12-4-2011
01-19-200
1/1/2011
03/03/1900
```

The focus here is on string manipulation and not file IO.

My try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in;
    string s;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the input file name\n";
    cin >> s;
    in.open(s);
    if (in) {
        // Logic goes here
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nCouldn't locate the file.\n";
    }
    cin.get(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is May 5 and January both 01 and 1? As a suggestion, you might want to post your Java solution for context (maybe as a link rather than code for that one only) and what you've tried to do in C++.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some code for us to start with?

Comment: So I was thinking of using getline(string) method to read the string but how to proceed from there?

Comment: How did you do it in Java? C++ probably has something very similar.

Comment: I used string split method but I don't know any in C++

Comment: Boost has one. Honestly, a regex for this would be pretty simple.

Comment: @chris made a good point. You're asking for rather inconsistent data output based on input. Do you want January to be 01 or just 1? Do you want March to be 03 or just 3?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to read in and parse this data is by reading one line at a time using `std::getline()` and then using an `std::istringstream` to convert each line into a stream. That way we can just use the extraction operator `>>` to get the values.

**A bit like this:**

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    if(!ifs)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: can't open file." << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    // working variable for reading in data
    unsigned year;
    unsigned date;
    std::string skip;
    std::string month;
    std::string separator;

    unsigned line_number = 0;

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line at a time
    {
        ++line_number;

        // convert line to input stream
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        // January 1st, 2011, /
        if(!(iss >> month >> date >> skip >> year >> skip >> separator))
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: parsing: " << line << " line: " << line_number << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        // sanitize input values
        if(year < 1000 || year > 3000)
        {
            std::cout << "WARN: bad year: " << line << " line: " << line_number << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        // process and output in relevant format
        // (change month string to number etc...)

        std::cout << month << separator << date << separator << year << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve upon this, but it seems to work for me and might get you started.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void superRobustDateParser(string date){
    string month, crap1, crap2;
    int day, year;

    istringstream iss(date);

    char delimiter = date[date.length() - 1];

    iss >> month >> day >> crap1 >> year >> crap2;

    // I leave this to you to find a more efficient method
    int monthNum;
    if(month == "May")      monthNum = 5; 
    if(month == "December") monthNum = 12; // etc.

    cout << monthNum << delimiter << day << delimiter << year << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string date1 ("May 3rd, 2014, /");
    string date2 ("December 4th, 2011, -");

    superRobustDateParser(date1);
    superRobustDateParser(date2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 5/3/2014 
 12-4-2011
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/P1v14E